# Is .bss not a part of final ELF?

Tags: memory-management, linker, loader, u-boot

Here below is the linker descriptor file which is an input to `GNU LD` to build an u-boot ELF for an embedded system

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00000000;

    . = ALIGN(4);
    .text   :
    {
        arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.o  (.text)
        *(.text)
    }

    . = ALIGN(4);
    .rodata : { *(SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT(SORT_BY_NAME(.rodata*))) }

    . = ALIGN(4);
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    . = ALIGN(4);

    . = .;
    __u_boot_cmd_start = .;
    .u_boot_cmd : { *(.u_boot_cmd) }
    __u_boot_cmd_end = .;

    . = CONFIG_SYS_NAND_U_BOOT_SIZE + CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE;
    . = ALIGN(4);

    .rel.dyn : {
        __rel_dyn_start = .;
        *(.rel*)
        __rel_dyn_end = .;
    }

    .dynsym : {
        __dynsym_start = .;
        *(.dynsym)
    }

    .bss : {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
         . = ALIGN(4);
        _end = .;
    }

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.dynstr*) }
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.dynamic*) }
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.plt*) }
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.interp*) }
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.gnu*) }
}
```

and the macro `CONFIG_SYS_NAND_U_BOOT_SIZE` is a option of final size of u-boot, and the `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` holds the base address of the text, now my doubt is **why is the `.bss` is been placed outside the ELF allowed size ??**

was it been put out of ELF , no ! when i have done the objdump of the ELF it was present in it, see the pic below

[image]

Comment: Why are you concerned with the ELF?  How are you going to use U-Boot?  Typically it is the .bin image file that is executed.

Comment: yes you are right, but what concerns me is in the `LDS` file, an `LDS` file describes the output ELF file which section goes where in file, but why does the LDS describes the .bss to be out of the ELF size  ?